# Is it good way to user dao when assembling dto to entity or not?

Tags: java, converting, repository, hibernate, dto

I have User entity that has relationship to other entities(Order,Profile)
When I assemble entity from dto and back I need assemble order and profile entity too.

User entity:

```
@Table(name = "user_info")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1789771068899105277L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "userId",columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID userId ;
    @Column(name = "login", unique = true, length = 20)
    private String login;
    @Column(name = "userPassword", length = 100)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "userEmail", unique = true, length = 320)
    private String userEmail;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Profile profile;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return Objects.equals(getUserId(), user.getUserId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getUserId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("User{");
        sb.append("userId=").append(userId);
        sb.append(", login='").append(login).append('\'');
        sb.append(", password='").append(password).append('\'');
        sb.append(", userEmail='").append(userEmail).append('\'');
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}




    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId(), getUserAuthority());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Role{");
        sb.append("id=").append(id);
        sb.append(", userAuthority='").append(userAuthority).append('\'');
        sb.append(", user=").append(user);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

For example If I need transform User entity to Dto I need assembler:

```
public interface Assembler <E,D>{
    D mergeAggregateIntoDto(E entity);
    E mergeDtoIntoAggregate(D dto);
}
@Service
public class UserAssembler implements Assembler<User, UserDto>{
    @Autowired
    private CarDao carDao;

    @Override
    public UserDto mergeAggregateIntoDto(User entity) {
      UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
      userDto.setUserId(entity.getUserId());
      userDto.setUserEmail(entity.getUserEmail());
      userDto.setLogin(entity.getLogin());
      userDto.setPassword(entity.getPassword());
      userDto.setProfile(mergeAggregateIntoDto(entity.getProfile()));
      userDto.setRoles(entity.getRoles().stream().map(this::mergeAggregateIntoDto).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
      userDto.setOrders(entity.getOrders().stream().map(this::mergeAggregateIntoDto).collect(Collectors.toList()));

      return userDto;
    }

    @Override
    public User mergeDtoIntoAggregate(UserDto dto) {
        User user = new User();
        Map<UUID,Car> uuidCarMap = getCars(dto);
        Profile profile = mergeDtoIntoAggregate(dto.getProfile());
        profile.setUser(user);
        user.setUserId(dto.getUserId());
        user.setUserEmail(dto.getUserEmail());
        user.setLogin(dto.getLogin());
        user.setPassword(dto.getPassword());
        user.setProfile(profile);
        user.setRoles(dto.getRoles().stream().map(roleDto->{
            Role role = mergeDtoIntoAggregate(roleDto);
            role.setUser(user);
            return role;
        }).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
        user.setOrders(dto.getOrders().stream().map(orderDto -> {
            Order order = mergeDtoIntoAggregate(orderDto);
            order.setUser(user);
            order.setCar(uuidCarMap.get(orderDto.getCarId()));
            return order;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return user;
    }

    private Map<UUID, Car> getCars(UserDto userDto){
        List<UUID> carIds = userDto.getOrders().stream().map(OrderDto::getCarId).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Car> cars = carDao.findByIds(carIds);
        return cars.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Car::getCarId, Function.identity()));
    }

    private ProfileDto mergeAggregateIntoDto(Profile profile){
        ProfileDto profileDto = new ProfileDto();
        profileDto.setProfileId(profile.getProfileId());
        profileDto.setUserId(profile.getUser().getUserId());
        profileDto.setAccountBalance(profile.getAccountBalance());
        profileDto.setUserFirstName(profile.getUserFirstName());
        profileDto.setUserSurName(profile.getUserSurName());
        profileDto.setUserRegistrationDate(profile.getUserRegistrationDate());
        return profileDto;
    }
    private Profile mergeDtoIntoAggregate(ProfileDto profileDto){
        Profile profile = new Profile();
        profile.setProfileId(profileDto.getProfileId());
        profile.setAccountBalance(profileDto.getAccountBalance());
        profile.setUserFirstName(profileDto.getUserFirstName());
        profile.setUserSurName(profileDto.getUserSurName());
        profile.setUserRegistrationDate(profileDto.getUserRegistrationDate());
        return profile;
    }

    private RoleDto mergeAggregateIntoDto(Role role){
        RoleDto roleDto = new RoleDto();
        roleDto.setId(role.getId());
        roleDto.setUserAuthority(role.getUserAuthority());
        roleDto.setUserId(role.getUser().getUserId());
        return roleDto;
    }
    private Role mergeDtoIntoAggregate(RoleDto roleDto){
        Role role = new Role();
        role.setUserAuthority(roleDto.getUserAuthority());
        role.setId(roleDto.getId());
        return role;
    }
    private OrderDto mergeAggregateIntoDto(Order order){
        OrderDto orderDto = new OrderDto();
        orderDto.setOrderCost(order.getOrderCost());
        orderDto.setOrderDate(order.getOrderDate());
        orderDto.setOrderId(order.getOrderId());
        orderDto.setUserAddress(order.getUserAddress());
        orderDto.setUserDestination(order.getUserDestination());
        orderDto.setUserId(order.getUser().getUserId());
        orderDto.setCarId(order.getCar().getCarId());
        return orderDto;
    }
    private Order mergeDtoIntoAggregate(OrderDto orderDto){
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setOrderId(orderDto.getOrderId());
        order.setOrderCost(orderDto.getOrderCost());
        order.setUserAddress(orderDto.getUserAddress());
        order.setUserDestination(orderDto.getUserDestination());
        order.setOrderDate(orderDto.getOrderDate());
        return order;
    }

}
```

So I used dao in assembler and I want to know can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: This question actually reads like it should belong to stackoverflow rather than codereview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Entity Relationships

First you could draw the ER diagram to visualize entity-relations.
An UML class-diagram for `Order` could do, like this:

```
,----------------.
|Order           |
|----------------|
|customer: User  |
|orderedAt : Date|
|items: Car[]    |
`----------------'
```

Relations:

- an order has exactly a single customer of type `User` (is ordered by)
- an order is submitted at a specific date of type `Date` (is ordered at)
- an order can have zero, one or many items of type `Car` (has order line items)

#### Class Design

A valid order must at least fulfill the two *is*-relationships.

```java
class Order {
    final Date orderedAt;
    final User customer;
    final List<Car> lineItems = new ArrayList<Car>();

    public Order(User customer, Date orderedAt) {
        this.orderedAt = orderedAt;
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public Order(User customer) {
        this(customer, new Date());  // default: ordered today
    }

    public Address getInvoiceAddress() {
        return this.customer.getUserAddress();  // delegate to customer (user)
    }

    public Address getDeliveryAddress() {
        return this.customer.getDestinationAddress();  // delegate to customer (user)
    }

    public void addItem(Car item) {
        this.lineItems.add(item);
    }
}
```

This shows, that you can simply construct an order by passing a `User` object. The other attributes (e.g. addresses) can be derived from the customer or user (delegation).

#### Mapping: from DTO to Entity and vice-versa

For this *mapping* there are plenty of [mapping frameworks](https://www.baeldung.com/java-performance-mapping-frameworks) like *MapStruct*, *Dozer* etc.

You can also implement the [Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern#Java) yourself, which fits pretty well here.

#### Hibernate: is an OR-mapper already!

*Hiberernate* is often described as **object-relational mapper** (OR-mapper).

Because it maps from object-oriented structures (expressed in Java classes) to relational data structures (expressed in database tables) and back.

The fact, that you are using the JPA-annotations `@Entity` and `@Table`  on the class describes exactly this mapping.

When properly using *Hibernate* and *JPA* (and their annotations), then you don't need further mapping frameworks or assembly-services.